# SubsamplingScaleImageView initial zoom and position

Tags: android

I am using **Dave Morrissey's** gorgeous library https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view , especially `SubsamplingScaleImageView` and I want image inside this view initialised with scale 100% and centered. There is method `setScaleAndCenter(float, PointF)`, first parameter is scale, I set it to `1f`, the second is point describing center but I don't know which values it should have.

My image has 2000x3000 px, I was trying set `x` and `y` of center point to `1000` and `1500`, also I was trying something like `0.5f`, `50` (percents) but it doesn't work.

How to calculate values for `setScaleAndCenter(float, PointF)` in order to center image?

Comment: `setScaleAndCenter(2f, new PointF(100, 1500))` should work but it depends on when you call it - if you call it before setting the image asset name or orientation, the view's state is reset. Can you post your code?

Comment: It works! Actually I set scale and center before asset file. I have another question, why scale is `2f` not `1f`?

Comment: That's just an example - 1f would give you 1:1 pixel mapping, which on a high density tablet screen may not be zoomed in much, so using 2f is better for demonstrating that it's working.

Comment: Everything works great except one another problem, in order to view images in short time I am using scaled images as thumbnails and if user double-tap on this thumbnail I overlay `SubsamplingScaleImageView` to show image in full resolution but old thumbnail is still in memory which results `OutOfMemory`. I think I should start new `Activity` with `SubsamplingScaleImageView` but then I want to add callback: if image is zoomed-out I will finish `Activity`. Is there any way to add callback to `SubsamplingScaleImageView` called when image is zoomed-out???

Comment: I think that would be quite annoying for the user, because it would exit the activity when they aren't expecting it, but you can do it if you extend the class and add a listener interface with callbacks from the `onTouchEvent` method.

Comment: Thank you, does `SubsamplingScaleImageView` have method to get info about "image is full zoomed-out"?

Comment: No, but you can call the `getScale` method together with `isImageReady` to determine the initial scale. You can also calculate it yourself based on the view and image dimensions - see the private `minScale` method.